# Sublime Text 3 Build System Per Folder

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm working on C and Python and I'm so loving sublime text's siplicity. For this reason I wanna work both of them in sublime but also I don't wanna change build system when I change file. Is there any way to set build system for per folder?

Comment: Use two different [projects](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/projects.html).

Comment: Are you using a custom build system that names the file to build and run directly in the build? It's easily possible to make a build that compiles and runs the current file, regardless of its name.